# SQL query selecting multiple entries from key tables into different columns of the same line

Tags: sql

I am trying to create an SQL query which can select multiple entries from a table and input these into different columns of the same line.

Example:

Table1 "Person"

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      PersonID       |     FirstName    |     LastName     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      John        |     Smith        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Jane        |     Doe          |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Table2 "PhoneType"

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      PhoneTypeID    |     Name         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      Home        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Work        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |      Mobile      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Table3 "PhoneNumber"

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      PersonID       |     PhoneTypeID  |     PhoneNumber  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      1           |     12300        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      1           |     45600        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      2           |     78900        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Expected result of the SQL query:

```
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|      FirstName   |  LastName     |HomePhoneNumber|WorkPhoneNumber|
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|      John        |  Smith        |  12300        |  NULL         |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|      Jane        |  Doe          |  45600        |  78900        |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

I want to select the Home and Work phone numbers from the table PhoneNumber and write them in separate columns of the same line.

The query should look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber AS HomePhoneNumber, PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber AS WorkPhoneNumber
FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN PhoneNumber ON Person.PersonID = PhoneNumber.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PhoneType ON PhoneType.PhoneTypeID = PhoneNumber.PhoneTypeID
WHERE PhoneType.PhoneTypeID = 'Home'
OR PhoneType.PhoneTypeID = 'Work'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the PhoneTypeID in the join clause

```sql
SELECT Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, HomePhone.PhoneNumber AS HomePhoneNumber, WorkPhone.PhoneNumber AS WorkPhoneNumber
FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN PhoneNumber HomePhone ON Person.PersonID = HomePhone.PersonID
    and HomePhone.PhoneTypeID = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN PhoneNumber WorkPhone ON Person.PersonID = WorkPhone.PersonID
    and WorkPhone.PhoneTypeID = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cf19c2/1

Comment: This way you can add another join for mobile number to complete the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You can use `correlated subquery` as

```
select FirstName,LastName,
       ( select PhoneNumber  
           from PhoneNumber  
          where PhoneTypeID = 1 and PersonID = p.PersonID ) as  HomePhoneNumber, 
       ( select PhoneNumber 
           from PhoneNumber  
          where PhoneTypeID = 2 and PersonID = p.PersonID ) as  WorkPhoneNumber
   from person p;
```

or use `conditional aggregation` with `left join` as

```
select FirstName,LastName, 
       max( case when PhoneTypeID = 1 then n.PhoneNumber end  ) as  HomePhoneNumber, 
       max( case when PhoneTypeID = 2 then n.PhoneNumber end  ) as  WorkPhoneNumber
   from person p
   left join PhoneNumber n 
     on n.PersonID = p.PersonID
  group by FirstName,LastName
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=0895076e4d85940accee1ffb8bcc7dea)</kbd>

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't think this is going to work, is it? How can the query know which PhoneNumber belongs to which Person?

"select PhoneNumber from PhoneNumber  where PhoneTypeID = 1" 
will return all the PhoneNumbers of that type. Not the one that belongs to the person

Comment: Thank you! Yes indeed, the edited version works great :)